# binding to my current presenter in caliburn without binding convention

Tags: caliburn

in caliburn when i work with binding convention, and name a content control "CurrentPresenter"
the framework automagically bind to the vm and locate the relevant view.

if i do this binding manually the view is not located..
how might i achieve this ability without the binding convention (my view is a user control)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should bind to View.Model attached property, which:

- figures out the correct view to represent the VM
- binds the view DataContext to the VM
- pushes the view in the ContentControl's Content property

Example:

```
<!-- Caliburn v1.x -->
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding CurrentPresenter}" />
```

The previous snippet works in Caliburn v1.x, while in Caliburn v2 and [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com) IPresesenterManager was renamed into IConductor (with some changes to interface members, too), so the binding should be:

```
<!-- Caliburn v2 & Caliburn.Micro -->
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}" />
```

Comment: 10x, but is there a way to bind a user control to a view model?
if i write in xaml some custom control tag how might i bind it to a view model?

Comment: The syntax is the same: <myns:MyUserControl cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}" />. 
View.Model attached property can push the child VM's associated view into any "container" in the hosting view. The only requisite for the container is having a property named "Content" or another equivalent marked with ContentPropertyAttribute

Comment: Cheers for this, it really helped!