# Caliburn.Micro : How to bind a specific Item of Conductor.Collection.AllActive to a ContentControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro

My goal is to have 4 different active ViewModels displayed in a grid on the ShellView. The issue is that I have not been able to figure out how to wire up a ContentControl to a specific Item in Items of the Conductor. How can his be done?

Here is a simplified version of what I and trying to do.

[SolutionExplorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5ufH.png)

ShellViewModel:

```
namespace ContentControlTest.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.AllActive
    {
        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            ActivateItem(new UC1ViewModel());
            ActivateItem(new UC2ViewModel());
            ActivateItem(new UC3ViewModel());
            ActivateItem(new UC4ViewModel());
        }
    }
}
```

ShellView:

```
<Window x:Class="ContentControlTest.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContentControlTest.Views"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ShellView" Height="450" Width="800"
        >

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding UC1ViewModel}" cal:View.Context="{Binding Items[0]}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding UC2ViewModel}" cal:View.Context="{Binding Items[1]}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding UC3ViewModel}" cal:View.Context="{Binding Items[2]}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding UC4ViewModel}" cal:View.Context="{Binding Items[3]}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

For simplification each UserControl ViewModel and View are Identical:

UC#ViewModel:

```
namespace ContentControlTest.ViewModels
{
    public class UC1ViewModel : Screen
    {
        private string id;
        public string ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ID);
            }
        }


        public UC1ViewModel()
        {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

UC#View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContentControlTest.Views.UC1View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContentControlTest.Views"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             >
    <Border BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="1"> 
        <StackPanel >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

For testing I have tried using an ItemControl and it works but doesn't give me exactly what I want.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Items">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create properties in your `ShellViewModel` something like `UC1`, `UC2`, `UC3` etc. You then need to change your `ShellView` to bind to `UC1` property.

```
            <ContentControl x:Name="UC1" />
            ...
```

Caliburn Micro should do the plumbing for you.

```
namespace ContentControlTest.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.AllActive
    {
        // Modify to implement INotifyPropertyChanged event...
        public UC1ViewModel UC1 { get; set }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            UC1 = new UC1ViewModel();
            ActivateItem(UC1);
            ActivateItem(new UC2ViewModel());
            ActivateItem(new UC3ViewModel());
            ActivateItem(new UC4ViewModel());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping this noob out, I really appreciate it! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The Caliburn concept of `Context` is used to map a view model to multiple views, usually through conventions and mapping namespaces. In this case, however, each of your view models maps to exactly one view. Hence you don't need to / should not provide a context.

Second, your view model binding cannot be resolved without exposing them as public props (as @Jack suggested). Ironically, the binding you used for `Context` is the right one for the view model binding.

Replacing

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding UC1ViewModel}" cal:View.Context="{Binding Items[0]}"/>
```

With

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Items[0]}"/>
```

Should do the trick.

Given the number of items is fixed it's better to follow @Jack's approach and reference the view models in a strongly typed fashion. Rather than relying on their index in the items collection. You can use either:

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding UC1ViewModel}" />
```

Or

```
<ContentControl x:Name="UC1ViewModel" />
```

Which are synonymous.

As you noticed the Caliburn `Conductor` really shines when used in combination with `ItemControl`. You typically don't need to have strongly typed references to the each of the `Items` then. That doesn't mean you can't use the conductor as you did, you still enjoy all the benefits of the managed lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you for adding the extra insight, it really helps get an understanding for the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is having an issue implementing the [perfectly fine] accepted answer, here is a more in depth answer:

1. Your main window that contain both (or even more than two) of your User Controls must be inherited from `Caliburn.Micro.Conductor<Screen>.Collection.AllActive`;
2. Your User Controls must be inherited from `Caliburn.Micro.Screen`;
3. You must also keep naming conventions in mind. If you use *MenuUC* as the name of a ContentControl in your View, also create a property named *MenuUC* in your ViewModel;
4. Initialize your UserControl as I do in Constructor;
5. Now you can use `ActivateItem(MenuUC)` and `DeactivateItem(MenuUC)` everywhere in your code. Caliburn.Micro automatically detects which one you want to work with.

> Example XAML View code:

```xml
<Window x:Class="YourProject.Views.YourView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="YourViewTitle" Width="900" Height="480">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Menu Side Bar -->
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MenuUC" />

        <!-- Panel -->
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FF707070" >
            <ContentControl x:Name="PanelUC" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

> Example C# ViewModel code:

```cs
class YourViewModel : Conductor<Screen>.Collection.AllActive
{
    // Menu Side Bar
    private MenuUCViewModel _menuUC;
    public MenuUCViewModel MenuUC
    {
        get { return _menuUC; }
        set { _menuUC = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MenuUC); }
    }

    // Panel
    private Screen _panelUC;
    public Screen PanelUC
    {
        get { return _panelUC; }
        set { _panelUC = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PanelUC); }
    }

    // Constructor
    public YourViewModel()
    {
        MenuUC = new MenuUCViewModel();
        ActivateItem(MenuUC);

        PanelUC = new FirstPanelUCViewModel();
        ActivateItem(PanelUC);
    }

    // Some method that changes PanelUC (previously FirstPanelUCViewModel) to SecondPanelUCViewModel
    public void ChangePanels()
    {
        DeactivateItem(PanelUC);
        PanelUC = new SecondPanelUCViewModel();
        ActivateItem(PanelUC);
    }
}
```

In the above example, `ChangePanels()` acts as a method to load new User Control into your ContentControl.

Also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197133/caliburn-micro-how-to-bind-a-specific-item-of-conductor-collection-allactive-t), it might be help you further.